# Basic javascript question about call() function: Conversion of non-string this values to strings

Tags: javascript

Reading MDN docs and have found this code:

```
const a = String.prototype.toUpperCase.call({
  toString: function toString() {
    return 'abcdef';
  }
});
// prints out 'ABCDEF'
```

Function `call` takes as first argument object with method `toString`, which means calling a function `toUpperCase()` on object or (correct me please if I'm wrong):

```
({ toString: function toString() { return 'abcdef'; }}).toUpperCase()
```

This code prints out 'ABCDEF', so how could `toUpperCase()` method invoke function `toString()` inside object that's what I don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `toUpperCase` passing it a `this` value that's an object with a `toString` method. Contrary to popular belief, `toUpperCase` **doesn't** assume `this` will be a string. Instead, it converts whatever `this` is (in your case, the object with a `toString` method) to a primitive string as one of its first steps (see the spec [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.tolowercase)¹). Doing that calls the `toString` method of your object (details [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tostring) and [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive)). At that point, `toUpperCase` has `"abcdef"` to work with, converts it to upper case, and returns it.

Conceptually (not *exactly*), `toUpperCase` does this:

```
function toUpperCase() {
    const S = String(this); // This is what triggers the call to `toString`
                            // on your object
    const L = /*...convert the characters in S to to upper case*/;
    return L;
}
```

---

¹ That's for `toLowerCase`, but [`toUpperCase`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.touppercase) is defined by saying *"This function behaves in exactly the same way as `String.prototype.toLowerCase`, except that the String is mapped using the `toUppercase` algorithm of the Unicode Default Case Conversion."*